# Are the new fields on Processes and Tasks in Viewflow 1.6.0 for library users, or for internal use only

Tags: django-viewflow

Viewflow 1.6.0 introduces new fields ("data" is a JSON field, and "artifact" support for a generic foreign key). They are present on both Processes and Tasks.

Are these intended to be available to library users, or are they Viewflow internal-use-only? I did not see anything in the docs or the github issues list to clarify the matter, so a pointer would be appreciated if I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's for library users, that allows using proxy models instead of real tables for keeping process-only data

Data field is the JSON. So it could be used with jsonstore field - https://github.com/viewflow/jsonstore that makes JSON data exposed as a real Django field. So it could be used with ModelForms as usual

Ex: https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/helloworld/models.py#L6

Articact allow to link process and your data models, without creating a separate table for that.

All of those allow avoiding joins to build all tasks from different flows for a user.